# Can't update specific columns? Only large string columns?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I'm trying to run some simple update statements on Cache 2008. Loging into the web portal. I'm able to run queries like:

```
update testspace.clients 
set requires_attention = 'Yes'
, notes = 'testsdfsd'
where id = '1||CPL62549.001'
```

The web portal runs and looks like it updated things but when I do a select statement requires_attention is updated but notes isn't.

Both fields are of type string. The only difference is notes is MAXLEN = 32700.

I've tested this on other columns in other tables. Any string column with MAXLEN = 32700 wont let me update it. Seems odd. Perhaps this is a coincidence and something else is going on. Seems strange that I can update some fields of a record but not others.

any ideas?

I'm new to cache but have experience with SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Cache are limited to 32000 characters. Setting the MAXLEN to a number greater than that is going to cause problems.

Set the MAXLEN to 32000 and it should be fine.

Comment: Well that's odd. At my new shop table creation is normally done through the UI. When I set the fields to be "scrolling text" that is the value the UI puts in them. I had tried changing the values but it didn't seem to do anything. I'll try again.

Comment: Well that can't be all there is to it. I decided to start from scratch and am working through the tutorial in the cache studio documentation.

Class AaronPhoneBook.Person Extends %Persistent [ SqlTableName = Person ]
{

Property Name As %String;

Property Notes As %String(MAXLEN = 32000);

Property Notes2 As %String(MAXLEN = 37000);

}

insert AaronPhoneBook.Person (Name, Notes, Notes2) VALUES ('test', 'tests1', 'test2')

    select *
    from AaronPhoneBook.Person

    update AaronPhoneBook.Person
    set notes = 'test4'
    , notes2 = 'test5'
    where id = 1

all works like it should.

Comment: yuk I guess formatting didn't work. Anyway created object with two fields one 32000 on 37000. I was able to do insert and update just like I would have thought. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Make sure you purge cached queries after changing a class.
Do $system.OBJ.Purge()
in the correct namespace

Comment: Rather unrelated comment: why are you doing a new development on a 5 year old product? Why don't you use the current version?

Comment: Sorry but still not working even after "Do $system.OBJ.Purge()"  Any other ideas on what could be blocking updates on only certain columns?

Comment: kazamatzuri - This isn't a new database. I'm working at a new job with an old database. Just trying to add a new table. Upgradeing is a project on the todo list but that's for another day.